# Monitoring works or identifying bottlenecks in data pipeline

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I am using google cloud datafow. Some of my data pipelines needs to be optimized. I need to understand how workers are performing in the dataflow cluster on these lines . 
1. How much memory is being used ? 
    Currently I am logging memory usage using java code . 
2. Is there a bottleneck on the disk operations ? To understand whether a SSD is required ? 
3. Is there a bottleneck in Vcpus ? So as to increase the Vcpus in workers nodes.

I know stackdriver can be used to monitor Cpu and disk usage for the cluster. However it does not provide information on individual workers and also on whether we are hitting the bottle neck in these.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within the Dataflow Stackdriver UI, you are correct, you cannot view the individual worker's metrics. However, you can certainly setup a [Stackdriver Dashboard](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/charts/#creating_a_new_chart_for_a_dashboard) which gives you the invdividual worker metrics for all of what you have mention. Below is a sample dashboard which shows metrics for CPU, Memory, Network, Read IOPs, and Write IOPS.

[image: Stackdriver Dashboard]

Since the Dataflow job name will be part of the GCE instance name, here I filter down the GCE instances being monitored by the job name I'm interested in. In this case, my Dataflow job was named "pubsub-to-bigquery", so I filtered down to `instance_name ~= pubsub-to-bigquery.*`. I did a regex filter to be sure I captured any job names which may be suffixed with additional data in future runs. Setting up a dashboard such as this can inform you when you'd actually benefit from SSDs, more network bandwidth, etc.

Also be sure to check the Dataflow job graph in the cloud console when looking to optimize your pipeline. The wall time below the step name can give a good indication on what custom transforms or dofns should be targeted for optimization.